Setting value of DataCardValue control in its OnChange property in PowerApps
I have a control in my PowerApps form called DataCardValue3
I am trying to set its value in its OnChange property:
SetProperty(DataCardValue3.value,3)
and I am seeing this error:
The property 'DataCardValue3.value' cannot be used in test automation
Any ideas ?

i came across this article and i followed the steps
https://daviddrever.com/2018/04/microsoft-powerapps-updating-a-data-card-from-a-button/
Here is what i did:
Step1-
in the OnVisible property of Screen1 i have this:
Set(AmountVar,SharePointIntegration.Selected.Amount)
Step2-
The Value property of DataCardValue3 i set to AmountVar (the new variable which i created in Step1)
Step3-
The OnChange  property of DataCardValue3 i have this:
UpdateContext({AmountVar:3})
thats it
now when i change the amount it gets set to 3
